# Dev C++ crashing on running large memory program

Tags: c++, crash

I am new to programming.I am using Dev C++ on Windows 7(x86).I am trying to run the following program.I don't think that there is a logical error causing the program to crash.The program is running on an online jugde(Codeforces).
What should I do to successfully execute the program?

My solution:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    long long a[100000],b[100000],sort[200000],temp;
    char aresult[100000],bresult[100000];
    char*sortpoint[200000];

    cin>>n;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i]>>b[i];

        aresult[i]='0';
        bresult[i]='0';
    }

    for(i=0;i<(n/2);i++)
    {
        aresult[i]='1';
        bresult[i]='1';
    }

    i=0;
    j=n+i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sort[i]=a[i];
        sort[j]=b[i];

        sortpoint[i]=&aresult[i];
        sortpoint[j]=&bresult[i];

        j++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<(2*n);i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<(2*n)-i-1;j++)
        {
            if(sort[j]>sort[j+1])
            {
                temp=sort[j];
                sort[j]=sort[j+1];
                sort[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        *sortpoint[i]='1';
    }

    cout<<aresult<<endl<<bresult;   

}
```

Comment: Don't allocate everything on the stack. That's most likely too much.

Comment: Would you mind posting the link to the exact problem?

Comment: Have you tried running a debugger to confirm that there are no logic problems?

Comment: You can not define a static array with such a big size because of the limit of stack size. Using dynamic array instead. For example `a = new long long[100000]` or using `vector<long long> a(100000)`

Comment: @ShaneHsu-http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/378/B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating too much on the stack. The default stack size for a thread is 1MB, unless it's been explicitly altered, and your arrays exceed that.

Instead, move the data onto the heap. For example:L

```
long long *a=new long long[100000];
```

Where you're only restricted my the available virtual memory of your process, which will be 2GB for a 32bit Windows application.

Comment: Since he is on C++, and he's aiming for a static-sized array, `std::vector<long long>` would be just as efficient. `std::vector<long long> a(100000);`

Comment: @ShaneHsu - yes, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a state known as stack overflow because of which the program is crashing. Mainly because there is static allocation of large array elements. Since in your program n is a value that is a variable and which is required in the loops testing condition I recommend you to dynamically allocate memory. This will save a lot of memory that is getting wasted. To do that you can use the new operator. If you want a better way to organize the data you may use a linked list, even. But it will increase the complexity of your program.